# Anyone know the future of Azure Blueprints?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Anyone know the future of Azure Blueprints? Is Microsoft embracing Terraform as a replacement? I don't mind ARM templates just trying to get a sense of the future for managing infrastructure.

I currently use ARM and Blueprints to manage our Azure subscriptions and infrastructure but I have been seeing a lot of posts around Terraform in relation to Microsoft and Azure.

I have also looked into other tools such as Bicep and Pulumi but right now I more interest in what the planned future for Blueprints is.

Comment: Hi, please ask this issue in [github azure blueprints site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-blueprints/issues).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Future or roadmap of Azure Blueprints:**

Most of the Blueprint resourcing is going towards [Template Specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs?tabs=azure-powershell) ([video overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-MtfehL80k&feature=youtu.be)) and Deployment Stacks, which is what Blueprints are eventually going to use under the covers. For authoring improvements, focus is [bicep](https://github.com/azure/bicep). The GA (General Availability) ETA is set for March/April when the new underlying resource types (template specs and deployment stacks) are ready and we can migrate everything over.

More info in this talk:

- [Blueprints migration plan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4E5DsC-RcU&feature=youtu.be&t=1285)
- [Deployment stacks overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4E5DsC-RcU&feature=youtu.be&t=1657)

Most of the Blueprint UserVoice asks are either already implemented in Templates/Template Specs, or they are something we will address with above mentioned future improvements to templates/bicep and stacks.

Lastly, even though the Blueprint service is listed as “Preview”, we treat the service as GA, which means even once a migration path is made available, we will continue to support the current Blueprint APIs for 1-3 years or until everyone has been migrated.

**Source of above information:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/177308/index.html

Comment: If this is true (after 2 years from this post) why is Blueprints the only mechanism for assigning deny permissions to Resource Groups?